# auditctl - logging when a user logs out

Tags: security, logging, audit

Is it possible to log when a user logs out of a session on Linux using Auditctl?

My current `audit.rules` relating to users are:

```
-w /etc/login.defs -p xwa -k login
-w /etc/securetty -p xwa -k login
-w /var/log/faillog -p xwa -k login
-w /var/log/lastlog -p xwa -k login
-w /var/log/tallylog -p xwa -k login
-w /var/log/secure -p xwa -k login
```

I can't see anything obvious in `/var/log` that I can watch, so I assume this is going to need some more configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This very much depend on what OS/distribution you are using:

- Fedora 20 and RHEL7 use `systemd`, so all login/logout actions can be viewed using `journalctl`:

  ```
  Jul 17 11:14:08 pris.crapsteak.org login[23256]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user root by LOGIN(uid=0)
  Jul 17 11:14:08 pris.crapsteak.org login[23256]: ROOT LOGIN ON tty2
  Jul 17 11:14:26 pris.crapsteak.org login[23256]: pam_unix(login:session): session closed for user root
  ```
- In RHEL6 these actions are logged to `/var/log/auth.log`.

For configuration specific to `auditd`, check out the [excellent introduction to the audit system by Scott Pack](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/01/a-brief-introduction-to-auditd/), from the example configuration in that article:

```
-w /var/run/utmp -p wa -k session
-w /var/log/wtmp -p wa -k session
-w /var/log/btmp -p wa -k session
```

> The next three files (utmp, wtmp, btmp) store the current login state of each user, login/logout history, and failed login attempts respectively. So monitoring these will let us know any time an account is used, or failed login attempt, or more specifically whenever these files get changed which will include malicious covering of tracks.

Comment: great. So adding wtmp adds a `type=USER_END` entry on logout. Thanks